# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, encode

```
email = 'aashita9317@gmail.com'
send_email('Happy Hour Update',message,
            from_addr=GMAIL_LOGIN, to_addr=email)
```

I am getting an error AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

```
def send_email(subject, message, from_addr=GMAIL_LOGIN, to_addr=GMAIL_LOGIN):
msg = MIMEText(message)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = to_addr
msg['Reply-To'] = 'happyhours@noreply.com'
```

Above is the send_email function it is referencing to, pointing to msg = MIMEText(message)
Please help

```
if _charset is None:
        try:
            _text.encode('us-ascii')
            _charset = 'us-ascii'
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            _charset = 'utf-8'
```

Above is the anaconda3 file it has referenced to in ~\anaconda3\lib\email\mime\text.py in **init**(self, _text, _subtype, _charset, policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explains charset encoding details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText

When adding headers, use e.g. `msg.add_header('Subject', subject)`
rather than `msg['Subject'] = subject`